# Error at webgl (uncaught abort (130) )

Tags: unity-webgl

I build a unity WEBGL but this error keeps appearing and i don't know why ?
i searched all over the internet but i found nothing.

```html
localhost says: An error occurred running the Unity content on this page. See your browser's JavaScript console for more info. The error was: Uncaught abort(130) at Error 
at jsStackTrace (WebGl.js:1:19540) 
at stackTrace (WebGljs:1:19711)
at abort (WebGljs:3:31704)
at o1r [Array.olr] (WebGl.asmjs:29:499959) 
at epk (WebGl.asmjs:4:238423) 
at Wlo [Array.W1o] (WebGl.asmjs:10:545384)
at mCk [Array.mCk] (WebGl.asm.js:4:412823)
at VVr [Object.VVr] (WebGl.asm.js:29:471994) 
at invoke_iiii (WebGljs:1:352706)
at J_q (WebGl.asmjs:22:501284) 
at .12q (WebGl.asmjs:22:540757)
at R_ (WebGl.asmjs:8:363400) 
at Q_ (WebGl.asmjs:8:363117)
at ERa (WebGl.asmjs:16:146190) 
at DRa (WebGl.asmjs:16:145304) 
at mFb [Array.mFb] (WebGl.asmjs:11:279534) 
at tkb [Array.tkb] (WebGl.asmjs:14:385194) 
at HKa [Array.HKa] (WebGl.asmjs:17:900965) 
at b8 (Webaasmjs:8:741635) 
at Q7 [Array.Q7] (WebGl.asmjs:8:731967) 
at uVr (WebGl.asmjs:29:468587)
```

Comment: same issue here... Did you find any solution?